# How to setup a domain on a Linux Server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain

I would like to setup a domain name for my linux server. I can currently access it as an IP, but for public it would be easier by a domain. I already bought it, it's on namecheap. I want to set it up so that when accessing mydomain.com it will show my web server. I don't have any interface I use SSH. Is it possible to point mydomain.com to a webhosting and sub.mydomain.com to my server?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a DNS, specifically an A record, which points your mydomain.com to your IP address. You can add multiple A records for different sub-domains.